# How to make this jQuery booklet plugin as a single page booklet?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using [jQuery Booklet plugin](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/), by default the booklet shown is display both(left & right) pages but I just want to display few part of left page and full right page.

just like this:

http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US/html/2

So please tell me how can I do this?

-Thanks in advance

P.S. I also want to cover maximum area of the page(920x550) using right side page only

Answer (score 1):

I also had this question and I asked the creator of the jQuery Booklet Plugin. His response was this:

> The plugin does not currently support a 1 page layout, as it would take a completely different set of animations to be functional. It is one of my most asked for features though so I will most likely attempt it sometime soon.

As for replicating a book similar to the [20 Things I Learned](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/) Book you may check out these two sites:

- [Now open source: 20 Things I Learned about Browsers and the Web](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/06/now-open-source-20-things-i-learned.html)
- [Case Study: Page Flip Effect from 20thingsilearned.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/)